# UIButton text of label not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, accessibility

Problem: If the user goes on the iPhone/iPad to "Settings - General - Accessibility - Increase Contrast" and switches on "Darken Colors" the text from my buttons disappears.

Here is my code for creating the buttons:

```
buttonCurrent = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
buttonCurrent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
buttonCurrent.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5);
buttonCurrent.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[buttonCurrent setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Add the reading with the current date", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonCurrent addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Thanks for the help.
I changed the code to:

```
buttonCurrent = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
buttonCurrent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
[buttonCurrent setTitleColor:self.view.tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonCurrent setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[buttonCurrent setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
buttonCurrent.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5);
buttonCurrent.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[buttonCurrent setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Add the reading with the current date", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It looks now like the UIButtonTypeSystem and it works also with system setting "Darken Colors".

Comment: Doesn't happen to me, might be something else playing.

Comment: yes, it works. only problem is that both button back ground color and text color are white

Answer (score 1):

all code is fine except first line.

```
buttonCurrent = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

UIButtonTypeSystem have default blue color as a back ground in greater than iOS7. You should always use UIButtonTypeCustom, so that it does not shows the effect as you are experience.
```

And also please give frame. I checked your code and you have not given frame for button. Please do that first.

```
UIButton *buttonCurrent = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
buttonCurrent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
buttonCurrent.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
buttonCurrent.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5);
buttonCurrent.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
buttonCurrent.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 80);
[buttonCurrent setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.5 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonCurrent setTitle:@"Add the reading with the current date" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonCurrent addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:buttonCurrent];
```

Comment: posted answer second time?

Comment: I omitted the lines with button size. I use AutoLayout with NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat.....

Answer (score 0):

All code is fine except first line

```
buttonCurrent = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

`UIButtonTypeSystem` have default blue color as a back ground in greater than iOS7. You should always use `UIButtonTypeCustom`, so that it does not shows the effect as you are experience.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code (see my edited question). It needs 3 line of code more for the color settings.